# Issue with the use of collide_rect pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to use the collide_rect function in pygame. What it says is that "descriptor 'colliderect' requires a 'pygame.Rect' object but received a 'instance'". Here is the way I'm using colliderect:

```
collision = pygame.Rect.colliderect(player, enemy)
if collision == True:
    keepgoing = False
```

So what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

`colliderect` is a method on the `Rect` class, so you invoke it by calling it on a `Rect` directly. Also, you should not compare directly to `True`. Some methods don't return a boolean value and it's generally easier and idiomatic to simply use the return value in the `if` statement:

```
if player.colliderect(enemy):
    keepgoing = False
```

This of course assumes that both `player` and `enemy` are `Rect` objects.

Comment: I'm just wondering how to be sure they are Rects. Is there a specific function to call because aside from the basic __init__ where I state their x,y,width and height it only has the render function where I say for it to be drawn as a rect?

Comment: Sorry, I can't magically know how your code looks like. You should know what `player` and `enemy` are since it's your code :-)